# Do Advaitin Sannyasis bathe daily?

Tags: advaita, sannyasa

Do Advaitin Sannyasis who have renounced rituals bathe daily?

Comment: Kindly use proper tags!!!

Comment: avadhutha advaitins don't bathe because they believe nude and ash smearing because they have renounced everything(but there are realized souls in them like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadasiva_Brahmendra), ocassionally bathing is done on kumbha mela

Comment: by that logic, you can also ask if they have renounced 'food' (why eat at all ?) or even renounced 'air' (why even breathe?). i think their point is to renounce 'as much as possible', they differ in degree of detachment. advaiti sanyasis draw the line at renouncing agni/yagna/upaveeta/shikha. some aja-gara-vriddhi sanyasis just stay where they are - whatever food falls on their lap, they eat. whereas vaishnava yatis draw the line at agni/yagna.

Comment: @ram Actually the reason I asked this question is because I read some verses that say sannyasis don't have to bathe, and also I know that some sannyasis in India today don't bathe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the Sannyasa Upanishads various kinds of Sannyasis are mentioned viz - Kuticaka, Bahuduka, Avadoota, Hamsa, Paramhamsa.

Among these, only for the Parmahamsa Sannyasis bathing is not ordained. **Others must bath.** Avadootas and Turiyatitas, however, are required to take wind and ashes bath respectively.

> "A celibate Kuticaka should give up his family, put away his bowl,
>   discard his water strainer, throw away his staffs, and forsake the
>   heavenly worlds." So said Prajapati.
>
> "Thereafter let him function without mantras. **He should bathe at the
>   start of the three junctures of the day**,  and, in deep
>   contemplation, he should realize his union with the Self.
>
> *Aruni Upanishad*

> A pot, a drinking cup, a sling, a tripod, a pair of shoes, a patched
>   garment against the cold, a loincloth, a water strainer, **a bathing
>   cloth,** and an outer garment: **an ascetic should avoid anything else
>   other than these.**
>
> Let him sleep on a river bank or in a temple. Let him not afflict his
>   body with extremes of pleasure or of pain. Let him bathe, drink, and
>   cleanse himself with water that is purified. When he is praised let
>   him not rejoice, nor curse others when he is reviled.
>
> *Laghu Sannyasa Upanishad*

> "A bath is ordained three time a day for hermits and Bahudakas, and
>   just once a day for Hamsas. There is no such rule for Paramahamsas.
>
> "Silence, yogic posture, meditation, patience, solitude, 
>   desirelessness, and equanimity: these seven are practiced by single
>   staffed ascetics
>
> *Narada Parivrajaka Upanishad*

> "He shall avoid speaking or chatting with women, looking at them,
>    dancing, singing, or laughing with them, and reproaching them.
>
> **"Bathing,** muttering prayers, divine worship, sacrifices, propitiatory rites, and rites such as the fire sacrifice **do not
>   apply to him, O Narada, in this world.**
>
> "Neither do divine praise, rites for ancestors, pilgrimages, vows,
>   categories such as right and wrong, injunctions, and temporal
>   activities.
>
> *Narada Parivrajaka Upanishad Chapter 6*

> "A bath is ordained three times a day for Kuticakas, twice a day for
>   Bahudakas, and once a day for Hamsas. A mental bath is ordained for
>   Paramahamsas, a bath with ashes for Turiyatitas, and a wind bath for
>   Avadhutas.
>
> A vertical mark on the forehead is ordained for Kutlcakas, a triple
>   horizontal mark for Bahudakas, both a vertical and a triple horizontal
>   mark for Hamsas , the smearing with ashes for Paramahamsas, a spot
>   with sandal paste for Turiyatitas, but none at all for Avadhutas.
>
> *Narada Parivrajaka Chapter 7*

Now, we just need to find out to which of the aforementioned groups the "Adavaitin Sannyasis" belong. By going through their [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dashanami_Sampradaya) I found out that they carry a single staff and which is a feature of the Hamsas.

> **Bahudakas are those who carry a triple staff**, a water pot, a sling , a shoulder yoke, a water strainer, a bowl, shoes, and
>   a seat; who wear a topknot, a sacrificial string, a loincloth, and an
>   ochre garment; who beg their food from virtuous Brahmin households;
>   and who thus seek the self
>
> **Hamsas are those who carry a single staff;** who wear a sacrificial string but not a topknot; who carry in their hand a sling and a water
>   pot; who spend only one night in a village and five nights in a town
>   or a sacred bathing place; who perform penances such as the one- and
>   two-day fasts, the krcchra, and the lunar fast; and who thus seek the
>   self.
>
> **Paramahamsas are those who carry no staff**; who are shaven-headed; who wear a loincloth and a patched garment; whose
>   emblem and conduct are concealed
>
> *Ashrama Upanishad*

**So, they should bath as prescribed for the Hamsas (i.e. once a day).** As, they carry a single staff, they are not Paramahamsas (for whom bathing is not ordained).

Comment: @Rickross baseless downvotes happening a lot here!

Comment: Well, it has been happening since ages ... @AkshayS